Why is the message being created by an instance of JOptionPane not shown?
I wanted to show a message without using static methods of the JOptionPane class and here's a Java program using an object of the JOptionPane class to show a message.
import javax.swing.*;
public class Sample {
    public  static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();
        pane.setMessage("Hello");
        pane.setOptionType(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        pane.setName("Information");
        pane.setVisible(true);
    }
}

It's expected to show a message, but nothing is shown as the result when it gets compiled and run. What's the problem?

Per the JOptionPane API, JOptionPane extends from JComponent, and so by itself, a JOptionPane object is not a top-level window, and so is not visible on its own, even if setVisible(true) is called. To create a visible window from a JOptionPane object, you must create a JDialog from your JOptionPane object. either that or place it within another container that is eventually displayed within a top-level window (as per any JComponent-type object). For example, and lifted directly from the API:
 JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(arguments);
 pane.set.Xxxx(...); // Configure
 JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, title);
 dialog.setVisible(true);

In my opinion, however, it is simpler and better to just use the static methods to create and display a JOptionPane within its own JDialog.

In some contexts, it looks like JPanel which cannot be shown without adding to an object of JFrame. Right?

@AmirMohsen: It's a child of JComponent, and so it would likely look more like a JComponent, which has some subtle differences from that of a JPanel.

BTW JPanel is also a child of JComponent... and JComponent's documentation , valid for both JPanel and JOptionPane, states: "To use a component that inherits from JComponent, you must place the component in a containment hierarchy whose root is a top-level Swing container."

@user85421: indeed. That is why I stated that the differences were subtle, including differences in default opacity, layout manager, filling and such.
